# How to configure NewRelic in spring-boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic

I have a rudimentary question about configuring NewRelic with Spring Boot 2.x.

Previously, I was able to have this in the build.gradle file:

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName 'com.fake.Application'
    agent = file ('/build/libs/newrelic-agent.jar')
}
```

But when I upgraded to spring-boot-gradle-plugin 2.0.4.RELEASE (up from 1.5.15), I get this error:

```
Could not set unknown property 'agent' for object of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension.
```

I see "agent" is no longer a property in SpringBootExtension class... So what is the best way to configure NewRelic?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped me with this issue. I do not, in fact, need to run the NewRelic that way via SpringBootClass. Since my application is deployed in a Docker container anyway, I can configure it to run in the Dockerfile, like so:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-javaagent:/usr/local/newrelic/newrelic.jar","-jar","/app.jar"]
```